# How i can add conditional steps in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Im trying to perform multiple steps in Jenkinsfile, these steps are containing shell commands which is taking time until i get the final output.

since these steps are dependent on each other, how i can add condition if the output of first cmd is equal to something ("session started")then perform the 2nd, if not then print some message =("string").

```
stage() {

    agent {
        docker {
            label 'MyDocker',
            image 'myIMG'
        }
    }

    steps {
        sh label: 'Creating container', script: 'docker run --privileged -d -p 4750:4723 --name mycontainer myimg'
        sh label: 'Building ', script: 'docker exec -it mycontainer test'
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `when` statement (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) or you might need to switch to a scripted pipeline job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need conditions like this at steps level, you have to use a `script` step and write some Groovy code.

```groovy
stage() { 
    agent {
        docker {
            label 'MyDocker',
            image 'myIMG'
        }
    }
    steps {
        script {
            def output = sh returnStdout: true, label: 'Creating container', script: 'docker run --privileged -d -p 4750:4723 --name mycontainer myimg'
            if( output.indexOf('session started') >= 0 ) {
                sh label: 'Building ', script: 'docker exec -it mycontainer test'
            }
            else {
                echo "This is the output: $output"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've added parameter `returnStdout: true` to return the output from the shell command.

To check the output I'm using a substring search `output.indexOf` to make the code more robust. You could of course compare 1:1 by replacing it with `output == 'session started'`.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i would like to ask you im getting output like this :

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.17.0
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

lets say i want to confirm if second line appears do this else do that, sorry for that im just new in this

Comment: @amrkdev This should be similar to above code, just replace the substring search: `if( output.indexOf('[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723') >= 0 )`